# Save a simulink model's sorted order to file

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model. The model has a sorted order(order of execution). When i save a model to file .mdl there is no a information about a sorted order.
I tried to save it to rtf file (File -> Reports -> System Design Description) but i expect more parseable format.
Are there any ways to save this order to any file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, as the sorted order gets determined on compilation of the model. It isn't a property of the model as such, rather a consequence of how the model is constructed. You can't save that sort of information to a file.

**EDIT**:

I stand corrected. There is a way to access the information, but you need to use the Simulink debugger. For more details, see [`slist`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/slist.html).